# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Invalid JavaScript property identifier character: ,

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have this code

```cs
var list = new List<long>();
long id = 202;
list.Add(2000);
list.Add(2001);
list.Add(2002);
var stringOfIds = string.Join(",", list);
        
var paramList = @"{'ProjectId':" + id + ", 'EntityIDsList': " + stringOfIds + "}";
Console.WriteLine(paramList);
var parameters = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(paramList);
Console.WriteLine(parameters);
```

for some particular reason, it doesn't Deserialize the object and it crashes. What I'm trying here to do is: transform a list of longs into a string, comma separated -> construct the `paramList` string and then deserialize it using `Newtonsoft.Json`. I believe that the error is somewhere in the `stringOfIds` but couldn't figure it out sadly. Do you know what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you have, `paramList` is not a valid JSON. JSON object has keys (and values if they are strings) surrounded with **double quotes**, not **single quotes**.

Corrected string with escaped double quotes:

```
@"{""ProjectId"": " + id + @", ""EntityIDsList"": """ + stringOfIds + @"""}";
```

If your purpose of writing this string is to convert it to an object, you should directly create an object. Also note that you cant print the objects with `Console.WriteLine`... you will need to convert this to a string first (`JsonConvert.SerializeObject`) then print it.

```
var parameters = new
{
    ProjectId = id,
    EntityIDsList = stringOfIds
};
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters, Formatting.Indented));

// output:
{
  "ProjectId": 202,
  "EntityIDsList": "2000,2001,2002"
}
```

If you want EntityIDList as a list of numbers, change the value of EntityIDsList to `list` instead of `stringOfIds`.

```
var parameters2 = new
{
    ProjectId = id,
    EntityIDsList = list
};
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters2, Formatting.Indented));

//output:
{
  "ProjectId": 202,
  "EntityIDsList": [
    2000,
    2001,
    2002
  ]
}
```

Comment: Each solution works in its own way but this was the most suitable for my problem so I'm selecting this as a right answer. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Right now your paramList looks like this:

```
{
    "ProjectId": 202,
    "EntityIDsList":
        2000,
        2001,
        2002
}
```

Which is not proper JSON. It should look like this:

```
{
    "ProjectId": 202,
    "EntityIDsList": [
        2000,
        2001,
        2002
    ]
}
```

So you should change it to:

```
var paramList = @"{'ProjectId':" + id + ", 'EntityIDsList': [" + stringOfIds + "]}";
```

Also at this point `Console.WriteLine(parameters);` won't tell you anything meaningfull, you should probably change it to `Console.WriteLine(parameters.ToString());`

Answer (score 1):

You have two "problems"

1. you need to add extra single-quotes around the stringOfIds bit
2. maybe it's actually what you want, but... this will give you a dictionary with 2 items with keys: "ProjectId" and "EnitityIDsList".

As the list is stringified you may as well use `D<string, string>` (or `dynamic`, depending on what you're actually trying to do.

I'm guessing you will want to have a collection of "projects"? So the structure in the question won't work.

```
[
  { "1": "1001,1002" },
  { "2": "2001,2002" }
]
```

is the normal json form for a dictionary of items

```
[
  { "1": [1001,1002] },
  { "2": [2001,2002] }
]
```

into a `D<string,List<int>>` would be "better".

Strongly suggest you create classes/records to represent the shapes and serialize those. Rather than string concatenation. If you must, then try to use StringBuilder.

Also, although Newtonsoft will handle single quotes, they're not actually part of the spec. You should escape double-quotes into the string if you actually need to generate json this way.

Maybe this is just a cutdown snippet to demo your actual problem and I'm just stating the obvious :D

Just a load of observations.

The extra quotes is the actual "problem" with your sample code.